# What would be an alternative if the VaR model is not acceptable?

Tags: value-at-risk

Assume we have a VaR model wich says : the lost should not exceed X for more 3 days and we come up with more days where the lost exceeded X, what is usually done for the VaR model ?

Do we switch to Monte Carlo VaR ?
Do we keep the same VaR and add a security factor in the computing the required capital ?
Do we switch to excepcted shortfall ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I would answer your question in the following way: Alternatives to VaR which share most of its helpful properties but not its shortcomings are the so called coherent risk measures. They have the following properties:

- monotonicity
- sub-additivity
- homogeneity and
- translational invariance

One example would be the conditional value-at-risk.

You can find more on Wikipedia:

- [coherent risk measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure)
- [conditional value-at-risk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall)